# Hiding size / colour options until you've made the decision to purchase

Tags: e-commerce

I was looking at the Topshop app and noticed that from your saved list area there are no options to edit your size / colour.

Also, size & colour options are not displayed on a product page until after tapping 'Add to bag'.

It's quite annoying that I can't track items in my size within my saved items and also a bit disappointing if I've committed to buy on the product page and realise it's out of stock.

I was wondering if anyone has any thoughts about presenting size options after adding to bag?

Thanks in advance :)

[image] [image]

Comment: Thoughts to what end? What UX concept/concern are you seeking to answer with an analysis of this process?

Comment: As opposed to some other apps, e.g. ASOS that offer size / colour options up front and are also editable within the saved items list... I'm wondering why Topshop chose to hide size options until the you've made the decision to purchase

Answer (score 1):

I'm biased - I was unfortunate enough to use the TopShop site on both mobile and desktop recently, and I think it's fair to say they have a long way to go when it comes to UX (I'm not going to moan here about their online gift-card purchase user journey, but it is ridiculous on nearly every step).

Anyhow, you are right. People who purchase online want to see product options, including colour and size (and the availability of which). You can strongly argue that these are key to the user choice of whether or not to buy the items.

So I don't think this can be explained in any other way other than poor usability. I'd argue (and even bet money) that had these options been available before the buy option, their sales would increase.

But it's possible I'm missing something which other may not...